# ReferenceError: event is not defined. i am using gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

in google chrome, everything work perfectly but in mozila-firefox it does not support on click listener.it display following error

**ReferenceError: event is not defined**

**My code is following**

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', onMarkerClick(_i,marker.getServiceObject(),event) );
```

Comment: but what is `event` ?

Comment: event is reserve word in firefox so it gives me reference error but when i changed the variable name from event to e my problem was solved.